# Botão para ligação de celular

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, whatsapp

Preciso de um código que ajude o visitante de um site (em Wordpress) a fazer ligações de celular ou acionar o Whatsapp ao clicar num determinado botão.

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o esquema de URL `whatsapp://` no atributo **`href`** de um *hyperlink* seguido da mensagem que será compartilhada. Por exemplo:

```html
<a href='whatsapp://send?text=testando 1 2 3'>Compartilhar "testando 123"</a>
```

Se o usuário tiver o aplicativo instalado, ele será inicializado permitindo que seja escolhido um contato junto a um campo de texto que permite editar a mensagem antes do envio.

Como ainda não é possível acessar o Whatsapp pelo navegador da mesma forma como é feita em dispositivos móveis — no *desktop* esse esquema de URL é desconhecido — talvez seja interessante esconder esse *link* e exibi-lo somente em telas menores:

```css
/**
 * Tamanho somente para ilustrar! Tenha em mente que
 * a instalação do aplicativo não é restrita a smartphones.
 */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 860px)
  .compartilhar-whatsapp {
    display: block
  }
}
```

Alguns links nas perguntas frequentes do aplicativo que cita o uso desse esquema de url customizado:

- [FAQ Iphone](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/pt_br/iphone/23559013)
- [FAQ Android](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012)

Comment: Ia ser interessante se ativasse o http://web.whatsapp.com quando a navegação for no desktop

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o **tel:000000000**. Ex:

```
<a href="tel:21912345678">ligar agora</a>
```